# What is the subscheme associate to a Weil divisor?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I see some notation as D_red， I guess this mean consider divisor as a scheme then reduce it. So what is the subscheme? Thank your answer or references.

Comment: Check any book on algebraic geometry, e.g., Hartshorne or Lazarsfeld. If $D=\sum n_i Y_i$ is an effective divisor, you can consider the associated scheme given by the ideal $I_{Y_1}^{n_1}\cdots I_{Y_r}^{n_r}$, or the reduced divisor $D_{red}=Y_1\cup \cdots \cup Y_r$.

Comment: Just like J.C. Ottem, said, given a divisor, it is called *reduced* if all of its coefficients are equal to 1.  The $D_{red}$ probably just means the divisor with the same support as $D$ but with all coefficients equal to $1$.